# Unable to play video after appium generates screen recording of IOS tests on browserstack

Tags: java, appium, appium-ios, browserstack, screen-recording

I am working on a framework for mobile automation using Appium.The tests run on browserstack real devices.  I am trying capture screen recordings of tests using the inbuilt Appium methods startRecording() and stopRecording(). It works fine with android tests. But with iOS somehow , the video is generated but when I try to play it it gives an error "Cannot decode".

If the tests run on browserstack what is the best way to decode and play them?

To start Recording I use,

```
((CanRecordScreen) AppiumDriverBase.getDriver()).startRecordingScreen(
        new IOSStartScreenRecordingOptions());
```

To stop recording and save the file ,

```
byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(base64String);
.
.
Files.write(Paths.get(fullFilenamePath), data);
```

Note: I have installed ffmpeg on my local.